# When to use Web server, installed application and service account authentication flows?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I want to build a clone of [Sheetsu](https://sheetsu.com/#) application using python. For this, I need to authenticate and authorize the user. I came across three types in OAuth 2.0 authentication flow. They are
1. Web server 
2. Installed application
3. Service account

Can Someone explain me the difference between all the three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[OAuth2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) Scenarios:**

1. Web server

*The Application which user interacts with is hosted on a web server. The user wants to delegate access to his data to this application*

Suggested OAuth2.0 Flow:-

Authorisation Code Grant.

---

2. Installed application

*Application which user interacts with is hosted on a device e.g. phone application or desktop application. Again, the user wants to delegate access to his data to this native application*

Suggested OAuth2.0 Flow:-

Authorisation Code Grant with PKCE.

---

3. Service account

*Application is hosted on a web server. The application requires a token to access data from an API, but not in the specific context of an end user*

Suggested OAuth2.0 Flow:-

Client Credentials Grant.

Or, Resource Owner Password Credentials passing in a service account username and password - some legacy APIs work like this but avoid this flow when possible.

There is another type of app as well:

4. Single Page App (SPA)

*The application which a user interacts with runs on their web browser server. The user wants to delegate access to his data to this application*

Suggested OAuth2.0 Flow:-

Authorisation Code Grant with public client if available else,

Implicit Grant.